# image processing : Segregating panel vs house like structure

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing

I am working on a problem that involves segregating solar panel vs house.
Both the house as well as panel are of same color.

**NOTE**: There are two houses in the image. I am referring to the one which is **bluish**.
PFB the image as well as my approach.

Any insights how to deal with such situations are welcome.

My approach

1. transform to hsv colorspace
2. Perform thresholding on hue component of the image.
3. Dialate/Erode.

   ```
   hsv_img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

   ## Thresholding values
   red_MIN = np.array([100, 10, 10],np.uint8)
   red_MAX = np.array([130, 255, 255],np.uint8)

   frame_threshed = cv2.inRange(hsv_img, red_MIN, red_MAX)
   k_dialation = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
   dialation = cv2.dilate(frame_threshed,k_dialation, iterations =5)

   k = np.ones((3,3),np.int8)
   erosion = cv2.erode(dialation,k,iterations  =8)
   ```
4. I also tried drawing contours perform shape analysis,
5. calculate area,

but as both panel and house have same shape from top and similar area, This approach doesnt work.

6. I tried template matching, 
   query image : House structure.
   I convolved over the image with query image to find relevant structure(house in my case)

steps 4-6 might work on this image but isnt **generalized** solution . A slight variation in terms of house position or a different shape house will break the algorithm.

Result after doing 1-5 steps.

[image: resulting image]

Comment: If you properly tune the threshold values, i think you can segment them out with decent accuracy

Comment: @I.Newton : you are right, if I tune my threshold value, I can segment them out. But as I have already mentioned, I want to build a generalized solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem involves segregating the solar panels with roof tops, you cant expect a generic OpenCV solution to work out. Using supervised learning methods can be one choice.

If you want to segregate roof tops from solar panels, one distinction we can observe is that solar panels have a certain repetitive distinctive pattern. This can be employed for the job. Let me introduce to you this method called **Histogram of Sparse Codes**.

It is more like the HOG, where the object is recognized by the shape (gradients), with the difference that HSC takes " by  learning  and
using local representations that are much more expressive
than  gradients ".

Then, as an improvement, you can try region proposal algorithms like Selective search instead of sliding window based approach.

HSC makes a dictionary of signals (Signals here are patches of images) from the train images and then reconstructs your test image from those signals. Then a histogram of the codes used to regenerate each signal is generated. Since your region of interest is unique, different set of codes are generated for your object and background and hence can make a distinction. Passing it to SVM can easily segregate your solar panels.

[Link to the paper](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~xren/publication/xren_cvpr13_detection.pdf).

[Link for selective search](https://www.learnopencv.com/selective-search-for-object-detection-cpp-python/)

You can use mlpack for sparse coding implementation. 
All the best finding solar panel datasets.

Image after selective search (No thresholding etc hence more generalized usage):

[image]

If you are finding all the above very difficult to implement. Find the "+" signs inside the selective search regions. You can use template matching or HOG. Then the region with more rate of +'s is the solar panel.